# Making a large quiz for iOS - 100+ Questions (using a .txt file or other) 

Tags: xcode, plist, text-files

I am trying to create a quiz app for iOS with 100+ questions. However, I do not want to have to design the UI by hand putting in all the values with the storyboard. I am trying to have pull values from a .txt file and use that to input values in labels and buttons. I need help doing this! I don't know how to have the compiler repeat the action of extracting the question numbers, questions, and answers that are all packed together in this .txt file and input those in the different objects every time you launch the game.

Am I being too unspecific?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check out this link. Yeah it's old and you have to do some converting to make work on Xcode 4.4 but it is all here... http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-game-development/13753-tutorial-quiz-game.html Might want to think about SQlite if you plan on storing a bunch of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Read the text file into an NSString. Have the data in the text file separated by commas. Use NSString's '-componentsSeparatedByString:' method (passing @"," as argument) to split all questions into an NSArray.